# How can I set condition to execute some steps just for particular amount of users

Tags: jmeter

How can I set condition in jmeter for a step that 80% of users will execute it and the 20% of users will not. Please help me for this.
I have a http sampler and I want it to execute just for 80% of users in the test, so when number of users (threads) will change the percentage of executed requests for that sampler will stay the same.

Comment: Can you give some code context for this?

Comment: this is the condition. i dont have code

Answer (score 2):

If you have some samplers that you want to work with just in some threads, not all, the easiest way is to add them to If Controller and in Condition add something like:

```
${__Random(1,100)} <= 80
```

In that case requests in that controller has 80% chance to run (fires only when random is lower or equal than 80). Of course it's not perfect, as sometimes it can go with +-5% of requests but it's fastest and easiest way I know. And with that sort of randomness it's more like real life experience.

Comment: its not working. i have tried with 10loops and this expression in if controller, ${__Random(1,100)} <= 80. but when i run this, its skipping the step everytime

Comment: try ${__Random(1,10)} <= 8 then. When you run just ten loops it can always hit somewhere between 81 and 100. More threads and loops gives results closer to desired percentage

Comment: I've checked it on my machine and the request was run 816 for 1000 loops, so it is close enough - 81%. Second round gave me 825/1000 (82.5%) so it's not perfect but it works.

Comment: thanks, its working but, when i run ${__Random(1,10)} <= 8 this for 10 loops then its run 9 times, that means it giving 90% and i need results in 20/80 ratio.

Answer (score 0):

I will add it as different answer as it is another approach to that problem.
You can add a Counter to your Test Plan (Add -> Config Element -> Counter) and set it like `Start: 1, Increment: 1, Max: 10, Reference name: count`.
When you will do that you can change your If Controller's Condition to `${count} <= 8`. It will execute the sampler in the controller just for 8 times, and last two loops won't do this.

Of course you can parametrize it and as value add the number of loops/threads you use and adjust the max number in condition from proportion, but if you are using just 10 loops that approach will be OK.

The only thing that is not so nice like in previous answer is that sampler will go for set number of times and then it will stop (so no randomness).

And just additional note about parameters for that case and how I've set it the easy way (with this setup the number of threads don't matter - it will always work properly):

- Counter with Start: 1, Increment: 1, Reference Name: Count and selected 'Track counter independently for each user' box
- Thread Group with Loop Count set by variable loopCount, which is also used to count the number of samplers needed to cover proper percentage
- If Controller with Condition set as `${Count} <= (${loopCount}*0.8)` (that 0.8 also can be set with some variable for easier control)

Comment: thank you, but i want the ratio of 80 and 20. like if i take 10 loops then it will run 8 times and and not run 2 times. and if i take 20 loops then it will run 16 times and not run 4 times. currently its running 8 times if i take 10 loops and 20 loops. its specific. it will run only 8 time in every condition.

Comment: Read the rest of the comment - you can parametrize it. Add variable loopCount, use it in your thread in Loop Count (as ${loopCount}) and in that If Controller use it as Condition: ${Count} <= (${loopCount}*0.8) - that's the easiest way I think