# given number of executions in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I would like to have let's say 10 concurrent threads (users) at max, but I would like for some controllers to run for 40 times. I thought I could do this using Throughput Controller, but it works only if the throughput is less than number of users. Do I have to use a Loop Controller or am I missing something?

```
Thread Group (10 users)
- Throughput Controller A 
- Throughput Controller B
```

A needs to have 5 executions overall, so I set Total Executions mode and Throughput to 5.

B needs to have 40 executions overall, if I set it as above with Throughput to 40 it will execute 10 times only, ie. up to the user count. Do I have to manipulate per user executions or loops to have 40 executions or is there any simpler way?

Comment: You should find this interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32691941/how-can-i-set-condition-to-execute-some-steps-just-for-particular-amount-of-user/32692452#32692452

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, the key is to put an infinite loop controller over the throughput controllers.

```
Thread Group (10 users)
- Loop Controller (infinite)
-- Throughput Controller A (total executions : 5)
-- Throughput Controller B (total executions : 40)
```

Now the test runs "infinitely" with 10 consecutive users but finishes after 5 executions of A and 40 executions of B.

Comment: One comment to this solution. It's better if you give specific number in the loop controller. With "forever" it tends to give some exceptions if your model is complex. you can set the loop counter high, to 1000 or something and it should work ok.